# Toggle one anchor link at time with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Would like to `toggle` my active class, so when I click on one link on the page, only one link is active with the class at a time, through out my page as I click on any of the links.  Could someone help me come up with a feasible solution adding to my code?

**JavaScript**

```
//Global definition
var activeState = $(".category-tree-with-article .article-list > li > a");
activeState.on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    // For class changes
    activeState.toggleClass('active');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.active {
    font-family:'MaxPro'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the class on all the other links and add the class on the clicked one

```
var activeState = $(".category-tree-with-article .article-list > li > a");

activeState.on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    activeState.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to do the current one then change -

```
activeState.toggleClass('active');
```

to this -

```
activeState.removeClass('active');    
$(this).toggleClass('active'); // can still turn on and off on this element
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `toggle` in this case

```
var links = $('.selector-to-your-links');
links.on('click', function(e) {
    var link = $(this);
    link.addClass('active');
    links.not(link).removeClass('active');
    return false; // I like this better than e.preventDefault() as it also does e.stopPropagation()
});
```